# DLL file not being properly injected

Tags: c, dll, inject

I am trying to inject a DLL and this is the C code I am using:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>


DWORD get_pid(char * targetProcess)
{
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snap && snap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
        if (Process32First(snap, &pe))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(pe.szExeFile, targetProcess))
                {
                    CloseHandle(snap);
                    return pe.th32ProcessID;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char * dllpath = "dllmain.dll";
    char * processToInject = "Robots.exe";
    long pid = 0;
    while (!pid)
    {
        pid = get_pid(processToInject);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
    if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {   
        void * loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllpath, strlen(dllpath) + 1, 0);  
        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}
```

The DllMain is just testing if it works by creating a message box:

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved){
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH){
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "INECTION WORKED!", "INJECTION WORKED!", MB_OK);
    }
    while(true){
        Sleep(10);
    }

    return true;
}
```

This hooks into a 32 bit game from 2005 and the main throws no errors, but nothing happens when I start the injection.

What I've tried:

- Compiling both the DLL and Main.c in 32 bit
- Injecting into other programs, both 32 bit and 64 bit (none have worked)
- Checking if the DLL path exists in case of typos (the file exists)
- Verified that the process ID (PID) is correct
- Verified that WriteProcessMemory returns true

Nothing has worked. Any help?

Comment: Does `get_pid` ever succeed? If it does, have you checked it is the proper PID?

Comment: @LHLaurini Yes, get_pid returns the correct ID, and just in case, I have also tried to manually enter the PID while the program is already running by finding the PID in the task manager.

Comment: Are you running the process as administrator? `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` will probably require that. Also, use [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to get more information about any errors you may be getting.

Comment: It is being run as an admin, and GetLastError reutrns 0, which leads me to beleive that there is something wrong with the DLL, but then again, all it is doing is creating a message box, so I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @LHLaurini I should add that GetLastError returns 126 when the DLL and C file is compiled as 32 bit

Comment: First: your code probably won't work if you compile it as 64 bit, since in that case `LoadLibraryA` may have an address larger than 2^32. So keep everything 32 bit. Second: 126 is [`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#:~:text=no%20volume%20label.-,ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND,-126%20(0x7E)). Which function causes that error?

Comment: @LHLaurini I'm not sure, since GetLastError gets the threads last error code and thus is 126 no matter when in the program I try to check it. However, since the hProc doesn't have an invalid handle value and WriteProcessMemory returns true, my best guess is that it is caused by CreateRemoteThread, since it is the only functions after it are the ones closing the threads.

Comment: Just tried using SetLastError(0) at the beginning of the program to see where the error occurs, and throughout the whole program GetLastError returns 0, so the error 126 in the thread seems to be caused by something else, since it doesn't occur during the main function in my program.

Comment: The value of `GetLastError` is only relevant after a function fails. Have you tried to load your DLL from another program? See if that works.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to load it from other games, but I still get the same result.

Comment: It does work when I try to inject into a program which I have created myself (another 32 bit process created in C).